# What is the purpose of CWinApp theApp and AfxWinInit in console MFC app

Tags: visual-c++, console, mfc

I was writing MFC console projects for some time and usually after wizard presents me with templated *.cpp I delete this code:

```
CWinApp theApp;
```

and

```
AfxWinInit( ::GetModuleHandle( NULL ), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0 );
```

I do it just because I am not sure if I need it. I was curious if it acctually hurts framework functioning in some way and debugged `AfxWinInit`. I found out that `AfxWinInit` initializes

```
AFX_MODULE_STATE
m_hCurrentInstanceHandle
m_hCurrentResourceHandle
```

and

```
CWinApp
m_pszAppName
m_pszExeName
m_pszAppID
m_pszHelpFilePath
m_pszProfileName
```

The latter is used in `CWinApp` functionality

```
CWinApp::HtmlHelp

CWinApp::ParseCommandLine
CWinApp::ProcessShellCommand

CWinApp::GetProfileString
CWinApp::GetProfileInt
CWinApp::GetProfileBinary
CWinApp::WriteProfileString
CWinApp::WriteProfileInt
CWinApp::WriteProfileBinary

CWinApp::LoadCursor
CWinApp::LoadIcon
CWinApp::LoadStandardIcon
CWinApp::LoadStandardCursor
```

But I don't know how former is used.
So it appears to me that if your program doesn't use `CWinApp`-aided work with *.ini files or *.exe resources (given that you already has access to command line parameters through `int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[]`), you don't need that `theApp` global variable at all.

My MFC console projects so far are:

- http parsers
- work with db
- file converters
- work with active directory
- docx, xlsx generators
- network share location monitor
- *.log file parser
- LAN proxy auto login

Some of them include aforementioned lines, some don't. But I never faces consequences on those where lines were removed.

Comment: MFC manages module state internally so that you won't have to pass the `HMODULE` (or `HINSTANCE`) value for per-module resources. Its implementation is documented here: [TN058: MFC Module State Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn058-mfc-module-state-implementation). Failure to get this right leads to very subtle bugs.

Comment: Also, the `Get/WriteProfilexxx()` functions aren't just for .ini files, they can also read or store data from the registry - you have to call the `SetRegistry()` function first to specify the location. And the `CWinApp` object is really convenient, holding often useful data like the handles or the names you mentioned. After all it doesn't use much memory or resources (singleton). I can't see any significant benefit in not using it.